# Running Generalized Least Squares in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statsmodels

I am trying to do some regressions in Python using statsmodels.api, but my models all have problems with autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity. So I thought of trying out Generalized Least Squares (GLS). I am not very familiar with running this form of least squares, so stuck pretty close to the instructions on the below page:

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.GLS.html

with the below code:

```
X = b2_final_Train[explan_vars]
Y = b2_final_Train[[ExognVar]]    
model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()

##GLS Component    
ols_resid = model.resid
res_fit = sm.OLS(list(ols_resid[1:]), list(ols_resid[:-1])).fit()
rho = res_fit.params

from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
order = toeplitz(np.arange(50014))
sigma = rho**order

gls_model = sm.GLS(Y, X, sigma=sigma)
gls_results = gls_model.fit()
print(gls_results.summary())
```

My problem as you can probably work out by looking at the code is sigma is a very big matrix, which overloads any computer I run it on being a 50014 x 50014 matrix. But as far as I am aware the GLS matrix is meant to be big enough for every error and that is how many observations I have in my data so that is how many errors I have. So is there something I am missing about running GLS which makes the problem computationally more manageable?

Thanks

Comment: OLS is a form of GLS. Running models on columns as large as rows seems off given degrees of freedom and sample size. Can you post data sample and describe model with named variables? You may need to melt data from wide to long format, then run linear models.

Answer (score 0):

GLS is implemented using a full dense covariance matrix across observations, the size is (nobs, nobs). This works only in small samples. (`nobs` is number of observations)

As alternative, the model class has a `whiten` method that can be used to transform the data so that it is uncorrelated and homoscedastic. This is used by WLS for weighting and can be used by subclasses of GLS to implement a more efficient whitening method that does not require the full nobs times nobs covariance matrix or its cholesky decomposition.

As example GLSAR https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.GLSAR.html uses the AR filter for whitening the data for serial correlation. However, it does not remove heteroscedasticity.

As alternative to estimating a GLS model:
OLS is still consistent if there is heteroscedasticity and serial correlation, although asymptotically less efficient. The correct standard errors can be obtained for these cases by specifying the `cov_type` argument in `fit`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Josef. I tried out using GLSAR with a rho of 3 and it didn't have much f an effect. However the main interest I have in the model is in making predictions, which from my research are not particularly by having heteroskedasticity?